# C# accessing a property of a generic class T

Tags: c#, generics

I need to accessing a property of a generic Class T 
I have this method in class generic

```
 public T calcuste(T obj)
 {
      calcaulte testobj= new calcaulte ()
      var t = GetValue(obj); // get the type of class for example that is calcaulte class 

      testobj.Id = obj.Id;// that is what I need to do accessing a  property of T obj 
 }
```

Comment: probably would help to show the class definition so we can see what `T` actually is

Comment: I'm guessing you want an interface https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx

Comment: or if you know the type you can cast to that type eg `((calculate)obj).Id` if Id is a field in your calculate class.

Comment: There is so much wrong with this code, that it is confusing.  Why do you define a var t, but never use it?  It is really hard to figure out what it is you are trying to do and what your problem is.

Comment: Consider using type constraints: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx#Anchor_3

Comment: the var not not necessary this just an exmple thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code.

```
public T calcuste(T obj)
{
    calcaulte testobj= new calcaulte ();
    calcaulte obj_calcaulte  = obj as calcaulte;
    if(obj_calcaulte  != null)
    {
        testobj.Id = obj_calcaulte  .Id;   
    }

}
```

You need to control for null since obj may be null or may belong to different class.

Comment: exclty what I need